# How to add an still image while combining multiple audio files in FFMPEG

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I combine multiple audio files with `FFMPEG` as

```
ffmpeg  -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 3.mp3 \
-filter_complex '[0:0][1:0][2:0]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[out]' -map '[out]' out.mp4
```

Then, I add a still image to the created video as

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i photo.jpg -i out.mp4 -tune stillimage -shortest out2.mp4
```

How can I add the still image to the first command to make the video in one single process?

Disclaimer: I deleted my previous question as it was unclear and asked a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i photo.jpg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 3.mp3 \
-filter_complex 'concat=n=3:v=0:a=1' -tune stillimage -shortest out.mp4`

Comment: Note 'concat=n=3:v=0:a=1'
Here the number after n= is the number of mp3 files you're concatenating into your out.mp4
So to make an mp4 file with 11 mp3's in it, use 'concat=n=11:v=0:a=1'

Answer (score 2):

To add multiple audio files with a still image, using ffmpeg :

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i Evergreen.jpg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -tune stillimage -shortest output.mp4
```

where mylist.txt contains :

```
file '1.m4a'
file '2.m4a'
file '3.m4a'
file '4.m4a'
```